# AngularJs validator with a form of many dynamically created inputs

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I'm trying to create a form of many rows of inputs using ng repeat. Each row has many inputs, with the values the user enters for each row adding up to the a value specific to each row e.g

Value = 20 input 1 = 10, input 2 = 10,
Value = 24 input 1 = 14, input 2 = 10,

From here the user can only submit the form if each line is fully completed and correct. Therefore i want to use ng-show="entireForm.$valid" to display the submit button.

Is this possible? I have been stuck on this problem for a number of days and am completely confused as I am new Angular. As of the minute I have created the view and setup the validator with no logic inside. Due to the amount of opinion out there I'm unsure if this is even possible with ng-repeat

MM.app.directive('lineitemvalidator', function() {

```
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$validators.lineItemValidator = function(modelValue,viewValue) {

            var totalInputHrs = parseFloat(scope.childForm.bill.$viewValue) + parseFloat(scope.childForm.drawDown.$viewValue)
             + parseFloat(scope.childForm.carryForward.$viewValue) + parseFloat(scope.childForm.writeOff.$viewValue) + parseFloat(scope.childForm.roundUp.$viewValue);


             if((totalInputHrs==parseFloat(scope.lineItem.billableTime))){

                 /*scope.childForm.bill.$valid=true;
                 scope.childForm.drawDown.$valid=true;
                 scope.childForm.carryForward.$valid=true;
                 scope.childForm.writeOff.$valid=true;
                 scope.childForm.roundUp.$valid=true;

                 scope.childForm.drawDown.$setValidity("drawDown", true);
                 scope.childForm.bill.$setValidity("bill", true);
                 scope.childForm.carryForward.$setValidity("carryForward", true);
                 scope.childForm.writeOff.$setValidity("writeOff", true);
                 scope.childForm.roundUp.$setValidity("roundUp", true);

                 scope.childForm.$setValidity("childForm",true,scope.childForm);
                  */
                 console.log("Form valid should = true");
                 console.log(scope.childForm);
                 return true;
                 console.log("Form valid = "+scope.childForm.$valid);
             }else{
                 /*scope.childForm.bill.$valid=false;
                 scope.childForm.drawDown.$valid=false;
                 scope.childForm.carryForward.$valid=false;
                 scope.childForm.writeOff.$valid=false;
                 scope.childForm.roundUp.$valid=false;
                 scope.childForm.drawDown.$setValidity("drawDown", false);
                 scope.childForm.bill.$setValidity("bill", false);
                 scope.childForm.carryForward.$setValidity("carryForward", false);
                 scope.childForm.writeOff.$setValidity("writeOff", false);
                 scope.childForm.roundUp.$setValidity("roundUp", false);

                 scope.childForm.$setValidity("childForm",true,scope.childForm);
                  */
                 console.log("Form valid = "+scope.childForm.$valid);
                 return false;
                 console.log("Form valid = "+scope.childForm.$valid);
             }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `ng-form` for this scenario. Each form will have some input and validations specific to its input fields. The parent form get automatically marked as `$valid` or `$invalid` if any of the child form validation fails.

The setup would look something like this:

```
<form name='entireForm'>\
   <ng-form name='formChild' ng-repeat='item in items'>
       <input name='input1' ng-model='item.field1'/>
       <input name='input2' ng-model='item.field2'/>
   </ng-form>
</form>
```

Each `ng-form` can be validated individually and the overall state of the form `entireForm` is valid only when all children are valid.

Comment: The only issue is I am trying to create a table therefore each row is a member of the ng-repeat e.g <tr ng-repeat="lineItem in data" novalidate>. I am not allowed to use inside ng-form inside. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Also how I access elements specific to the child form. For example input 2 is child form 1, I want to access input 2 also to check its value? @Chandermani

Comment: Yes, you will have issues with table, maybe you can look at bootstrap grid based layout.

Comment: Depends upon where you want to access. The controller for the ng-model is available at formChild.input2, which you can use to get the view value and validate the view, but it is available within the ng-repeat scope only.

Comment: Remember is there is no validation error the value of item.field2 will match the input2 value, so you always have access to it.

Comment: Yes everything seems to be nearly Ok, I am able to access the other inputs and create a total. Within my validator I am totalling the inputs when correct setting all inputs to $valid=true, yet when they are all true the child form is still $valid=false. Any tips?

Comment: Post some code outline. Also you should not manually set $valid=true\false. You should use model controller.

Comment: Code added in original post

Comment: If after a change of input the values are equal I want to set every input as valid and therefore the form becomes valid, if the case is the same in the other child form i want to display a div @Chandermani